# apt-transport-https is failing

Tags: docker, apt-get, apt

I am using fedora 29 . During installing docker i gave `apt-transport-https` command , i am getting like this `---bash: apt-transport-https: command not found...`

I tried apt-get-update ,this also not working

```
[root@localhost ~]# apt-get update
Ign http://download.fedoraproject.org fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/ repomd.xml
E: Repository model not found for http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/ fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/
```

Answer (score 1):

`Apt` is for `debian-like` system, for fedora, please use `dnf`, see [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF?rd=Dnf) & [this](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf/).

And for docker install:

Please refer to https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/ to install docker on fedora.

Comment: do you know what's the equivelent of `apt-transport-https` in fedora?